# With delphi indy 10.6 tcpclient I get intermittent stream read errors

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy

I'm setting up a TCP Client/Server system where the client sends a header block, and optionally a string stream or a file stream, and the server responds with a header block with any error codes, and optionally a string stream or a file stream.  The communication work great with just header block transfers and header block transfers with string streams; the problem comes in when trying to transfer large groups of files.  File transfers from the server involve:  send the FileGet header, receive the FileGet response header, receive the file stream (FilePut is send the FilePut header, followed by the file stream, then receive the FilePut response header with any error indication).  The file transfers work flawlessly most of the time, transferring 279 files per shot, but somewhere within 6 tries I will encounter some type of error; typical errors are freeze up while receiving a random file stream, Assertion failure (...\IdGlobal.pas, line 4876) (indicating the stream was larger than the specified size I believe) while receiving a file stream, and sometimes an MD5 checksum mismatch between what the sender indicated and what the receiver calculated.  Here's the relevant code sections:

```
  TCommandTypeHeader = Packed Record
    CommandType: TCommandType;
    ErrorType: TErrorType;
    Location: Integer; //used as site id for ctAssignID/ctConnectUnit/ctNewSite/ctRemoveSite
    UnitId: Integer; //used as unit id for ctAssignID/ctConnectUnit/ctNewUnit/ctRemoveUnit
    DataType: TDataType; //type of data sent after header packet
    DataSize: Int64; //0 if no data  or  length of file stream/string data following header (in bytes)
    DataMD5: String[32]; //MD5 checksum of additional data
    FileLoc: Integer; //folder location within current site
    FileName: String[12]; //file name for put/get file commands
  End;

  TUsers = Record
    InActive: Boolean;
    InContext: TUserContext;
    InSecurity: TSecurity; //used to compress/decompress TIdBytes for security
    InIP: String;
    InAuthTimer: Integer;
    InAuth: Boolean;
    InSATimer: Integer;
    InConnected: Boolean;
    InXFer: Boolean;
    InGotHeader: Boolean;
    InTries: Integer;
  End;
```

Client Side

```
{ TReadingThread }

Constructor TReadingThread.Create(AClient: TOutTCPClient);
Begin
  Inherited Create(True);
  FClient := AClient;
  FClient.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := cRTime;
  FWaiting := False;
  FFileName := DataDir + PathDelim + 'TEMP.DAT';
  FTries := cCTries;
End;


Procedure TReadingThread.GetResponse(CTH: TCommandTypeHeader);
Begin
  If FWaiting Then
    Exit;
  FCTH := CTH;
  FTries := cCTries;
  FDone := False;
  FGetHeader := True;
  FWaiting := True;
End;


Procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
Var
  BufRaw, BufDec: TIdBytes;
  FS: TFileStream;
Begin
  While Not Terminated Do
    If FWaiting Then
      Begin
        If FGetHeader Then
          Try //try to get the header
            SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
            FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(BufRaw, SizeOf(TCommandTypeHeader) + 1); //get header bytes
            SetLength(BufDec, 0);
            BufDec := FClient.Security.DecIdBytes(BufRaw); //decode bytes
            SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
            BytesToRaw(BufDec, FCTH, SizeOf(TCommandTypeHeader)); //move bytes to header
            SetLength(BufDec, 0);
            FStrData := '';
            FTries := cCTries;
            FGetHeader := False;
            If FCTH.DataType = dtNone Then
              Begin //no extra data
                FWaiting := False;
                If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                  Synchronize(DataReceived);
                FDone := True;
              End;
          Except
            On E: EIdConnClosedGracefully Do
              Begin //server disconnected
                SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
                SetLength(BufDec, 0);
                FDone := True;
                FCTH.ErrorType := etServerDropped;
                FWaiting := False;
                If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                  Synchronize(DataReceived);
              End;
            On E: EIdReadTimeout Do
              Begin //no data received within 1 sec
                SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
                SetLength(BufDec, 0);
                FDone := True;
                Dec(FTries, 1);
                If FTries = 0 Then
                  Begin //no data received within 5 sec, bad packet
                    FCTH.ErrorType := etPacketFailure;
                    FWaiting := False;
                    If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                      Synchronize(DataReceived);
                  End;
              End;
          End;
        If Not FDone Then
          Case FCTH.DataType Of
            dtString:
              Try //get the string data
                SetLength(BufDec, 0);
                FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(BufDec, FCTH.DataSize + 1);
                FStrData := FClient.Security.DecStr(BufDec); //decode username/password
                SetLength(BufDec, 0);
                If FCTH.CommandType = ctFileGet Then
                  Begin //create empty file
                    If ForcePath(ExtractFileDir(FFileName)) Then
                      Try
                        If FileExists(FFileName) Then
                          DeleteFile(FFileName);
                        FS := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmOpenWrite Or fmCreate);
                      Finally
                        FreeAndNil(FS);
                      End
                    Else
                      FCTH.ErrorType := etCannotCreatePath;
                  End;
                FWaiting := False;
                If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                  Synchronize(DataReceived);
              Except
                On E: EIdConnClosedGracefully Do
                  Begin //server disconnected
                    FCTH.ErrorType := etServerDropped;
                    FWaiting := False;
                    If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                      Synchronize(DataReceived);
                  End;
                On E: EIdReadTimeout Do
                  Begin //no data received within 1 sec
                    SetLength(BufDec, 0);
                    Dec(FTries, 1);
                    If FTries = 0 Then
                      Begin //no data received within 5 sec, bad packet
                        FCTH.ErrorType := etPacketFailure;
                        FWaiting := False;
                        If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                          Synchronize(DataReceived);
                      End;
                  End;
              End;
            dtStream:
              If ForcePath(ExtractFileDir(FFileName)) Then
                Begin //get the stream data
                  If FileExists(FFileName) Then
                    DeleteFile(FFileName);
                  FS := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmOpenWrite Or fmCreate);
                  Try
                    Try
                      If FCTH.DataSize > 0 Then
                        Begin
                          FS.Position := 0;
                          FClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
                          FClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, FCTH.DataSize, False);
                        End;
                    Finally
                      FreeAndNil(FS);
                    End;
                    FWaiting := False;
                    If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                      Synchronize(DataReceived);
                  Except
                    On E: EIdConnClosedGracefully Do
                      Begin //server disconnected
                        FCTH.ErrorType := etServerDropped;
                        FWaiting := False;
                        If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                          Synchronize(DataReceived);
                      End;
                    On E: EIdReadTimeout Do
                      Begin //no data received within 1 sec
                        Dec(FTries, 1);
                        If FTries = 0 Then
                          Begin //no data received within 5 sec, bad packet
                            FCTH.ErrorType := etPacketFailure;
                            FWaiting := False;
                            If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                              Synchronize(DataReceived);
                          End;
                      End;
                  End;
                End
              Else
                Begin
                  FCTH.ErrorType := etCannotCreatePath;
                  FClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.clear;
                  FWaiting := False;
                  If Assigned(FOnData) Then
                    Synchronize(DataReceived);
                End;
          End;
      End;
End;


Procedure TReadingThread.DataReceived;
Begin
  If Assigned(FOnData) Then
    FOnData(FCTH, FStrData);
End;
```

Server Side

```
Procedure TFK30MasForm.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
Var
  BufRaw, BufDec: TIdBytes;
  CTH: TCommandTypeHeader;
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
  FS: TFileStream;
Begin
  I := TUserContext(AContext).UserID;
  If Not FUsers[I].InGotHeader Then //False after every transfer
    Try
      If FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size = 0 Then// IsEmpty Then
        Begin //no data yet
          FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
          FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(0);
        End;
      If FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size >=
         (SizeOf(TCommandTypeHeader) + 1) Then
        Begin //get header
          SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
          FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(BufRaw, SizeOf(TCommandTypeHeader) + 1); //get header bytes
          SetLength(BufDec, 0);
          BufDec := FUsers[I].InSecurity.DecIdBytes(BufRaw); //decode bytes
          BytesToRaw(BufDec, CTH, SizeOf(TCommandTypeHeader)); //move bytes to header
          SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
          SetLength(BufDec, 0);
          If CTH.DataType = dtNone Then
            Begin //single packet commands
              FUsers[I].InSATimer := cSATime; //reset the stay alive timer
              FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
              Case CTH.CommandType Of
                  ... //code irrelevant to issue
                ctFileGet:
                  Begin //User downloading a file
                    PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SFileGetNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep, CTH);
                  End;
                  ... //code irrelevant to issue
              End;
            End
          Else
            Begin //2 packet commands
              FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
              FUsers[I].InGotHeader := True; //now process 2nd packet
            End;
      End;
        End
      Else
        Begin //signal a packet failure
          SetLength(BufRaw, 0);
          Dec(FUsers[I].InTries, 1);
          If FUsers[I].InTries = 0 Then
            Begin //invalid packet length
              FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
              CTH.CommandType := ctFailure;
              CTH.ErrorType := etInvalidHeader;
              CTH.Location := 0;
              CTH.UnitId := 0;
              CTH.FileLoc := Ord(flRoot);
              CTH.FileName := '            ';
              CTH.DataType := dtNone;
              CTH.DataMD5 := '                                ';
              CTH.DataSize := 0;
              FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.clear;
              PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SPacketErrorNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep +
                                          'invalid header received!' + cCSep, CTH);
            End;
        End;
    Except
      On E: Exception Do
        Begin
          FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
          Raise;
        End;
    End;
  If FUsers[I].InGotHeader Then //process 2 packet commands, string or file stream
    Case CTH.DataType Of
      dtString:
        Case CTH.CommandType Of
          ctAuthenticate:
            ...//irrelevant code
        End;
      dtStream:
        Case CTH.CommandType Of
          ctFilePut: //get a file from the client
            Try //stream commands here
              FUsers[I].InSATimer := cSATime; //reset the stay alive timer
              S := PCommon.GetFullName(PCommon.DataDir + PathDelim + IntToStr(CTH.Location) +
                   PathDelim + IntToStr(CTH.UnitId), CTH); //make the file name
              If S[Length(S)] = PathDelim Then
                Begin //error, no file name
                  FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
                  FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                  FUsers[I].InGotHeader := False;
                  CTH.ErrorType := etNoFileName;
                  PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SPacketErrorNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep +
                                              'no file name!' + cCSep, CTH);
                End
              Else
                Begin //download the file
                  If FileExists(S + '.TMP') Then
                    DeleteFile(S + '.TMP');
                  If PCommon.ForcePath(ExtractFileDir(S)) Then
                    Begin //make the path
                      FS := TFileStream.Create(S + '.TMP', fmCreate Or fmOpenWrite); //create the file
                      Try
                        If CTH.DataSize > 0 Then
                          Begin //fill the file if not empty
                            FUsers[I].InXFer := True;
                            FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
                            FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, CTH.DataSize, False);
                          End;
                      Finally
                        FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
                        FreeAndNil(FS); //close the file
                        FUsers[I].InGotHeader := False;
                        FUsers[I].InXFer := False; //reenable stay alive timer
                      End;
                      PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SFilePutNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep, CTH);
                      FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
                    End
                  Else
                    Begin //cannot create destination path
                      FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
                      FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                      FUsers[I].InGotHeader := False;
                      CTH.ErrorType := etCannotCreatePath;
                      PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SPacketErrorNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep +
                                                  'cannot create path!' + cCSep, CTH);
                    End;
                End;
            Except
              On E: EIdReadTimeout Do
                Begin //no data received within 1 sec
                  Dec(FUsers[I].InTries, 1);
                  If FUsers[I].InTries = 0 Then
                    Begin //no data received within 5 sec, bad packet
                      FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
                      FUsers[I].InGotHeader := False;
                      CTH.ErrorType := etPacketFailure;
                      PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SPacketErrorNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep +
                                                  'second packet not received!' + cCSep, CTH);
                    End;
                  Raise;
                End;
              On E: Exception Do
                Begin
                  FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
                  Raise;
                End;
            End;
        Else
          FUsers[I].InTries := cSTries;
          FUsers[I].InContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
          FUsers[I].InGotHeader := False;
          CTH.ErrorType := etInvalidCommand;
          PCommon.TMyNotify.NotifyCTH(SPacketErrorNotify, IntToStr(I) + cCSep +
                                      'invalid command received!' + cCSep, CTH);
        End;
    End;
End;


Procedure TFK30MasForm.SFileGetNotify(Const AMessage: String; CTH: TCommandTypeHeader);
Var
  I: Integer;
  S, FLoc, FUnit, FName: String;
  ErrType: TErrorType;
Begin
  S := AMessage;
  I := StrToIntDef(Fetch(S, cCSep), -1); //get the user ID
  If (I = -1) Or (Not Server.Active) Then
    Exit;
  FUsers[I].InXFer := True;
  FLoc := IntToStr(CTH.Location);
  FUnit := IntToStr(CTH.UnitId);
  FName := PCommon.GetFullName(DataDir + PathDelim + FLoc + PathDelim + FUnit, CTH);
  AddMessage('File> ' + FName, mcGreen, I);
  If FileExists(FName) Then
    Begin //source file exists, send it
      ErrType := PCommon.SendSCommand(FUsers[I], CTH.CommandType, CTH.Location, CTH.UnitId,
                                      TFileLoc(CTH.FileLoc), FName, etNone); //signal received okay
      If ErrType = etNone Then
        AddMessage('FileGet-File sent', mcWhite, I) //show good send
      Else
        AddMessage('FileGet-' + PCommon.GetErrType(ErrType), mcRed, I); //show error
    End
  Else
    Begin //send file doesn't exist message
      PCommon.SendSString(FUsers[I], 'FileGet-Error, file does not exist!', CTH.CommandType,
                          CTH.Location, CTH.UnitId, TFileLoc(CTH.FileLoc), FName, etNotFileExist);
      AddMessage('FileGet-file does not exist!', mcRed, I); //show error
    End;
End;


Procedure TFK30MasForm.SFilePutNotify(Const AMessage: String; CTH: TCommandTypeHeader);
Var
  I: Integer;
  S, FName, FLoc, FUnit: String;
  ErrType: TErrorType;
Begin
  S := AMessage;
  I := StrToIntDef(Fetch(S, cCSep), -1); //get the user ID
  If (I = -1) Or (Not Server.Active) Then
    Exit;
  FUsers[I].InXFer := True;
  FLoc := IntToStr(CTH.Location);
  FUnit := IntToStr(CTH.UnitId);
  FName := PCommon.GetFullName(DataDir + PathDelim + FLoc + PathDelim + FUnit, CTH);
  If ExtractFileName(FName) = '' Then
    Begin //signal no file name supplied error
      PCommon.SendSString(FUsers[I], 'FilePut-Error, no file name specified!',
                          CTH.CommandType, CTH.Location, CTH.UnitId, TFileLoc(CTH.FileLoc),
                          FName, etNoFileName);
      AddMessage('FilePut-No file name specified!', mcRed, I); //show error
      Exit;
    End;
  If CTH.DataMD5 = PCommon.GetFileMD5(FName + '.TMP') Then
    Begin //good checksum, save the file
      If FileExists(FName + '.TMP') Then
        Begin
          If FileExists(FName) Then
            DeleteFile(FName); //delete the true destination file
          RenameFile(FName + '.TMP', FName); //rename the temp file
          ErrType := PCommon.SendSCommand(FUsers[I], CTH.CommandType, CTH.Location,
                                          CTH.UnitId, TFileLoc(CTH.FileLoc),
                                          FName, CTH.ErrorType); //signal received okay
          If ErrType = etNone Then
            AddMessage('FilePut-File received!', mcWhite, I) //show good receive
          Else
            AddMessage('FilePut-' + PCommon.GetErrType(ErrType), mcRed, I); //show error
        End
      Else
        Begin //signal couldn't create file
          PCommon.SendSCommand(FUsers[I], CTH.CommandType, CTH.Location, CTH.UnitId,
                               TFileLoc(CTH.FileLoc), FName, etNotFileExist);
          AddMessage('FilePut-Could not create file!', mcRed, I); //show error
        End;
    End
  Else
    Begin //checksum mismatch
      If FileExists(FName + '.TMP') Then
        DeleteFile(FName + '.TMP'); //erase the temp file
      PCommon.SendSString(FUsers[I], 'FilePut-Error, file check sum mismatch!',
                          CTH.CommandType, CTH.Location, CTH.UnitId, TFileLoc(CTH.FileLoc),
                          FName, etCheckSumMismatch); //send checksum mismatch error
      AddMessage('FilePut-File Check Sum mismatch!', mcRed, I); //show error
    End;
End;
```

As you can see, I've tried putting in read timeout handling, the client will allow 10 tries of 1 sec read timeouts and the server will allow 5 tries of 1 sec timeouts before error responses/retries are triggered.

***EDIT***

So I changed the Client Reading Thread for the Stream section as follows:

```
dtStream:
  If ForcePath(ExtractFileDir(FFileName)) Then
    Begin //get the stream data
      If FileExists(FFileName) Then
        DeleteFile(FFileName);
      FS := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmOpenWrite Or fmCreate);
      FClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      Try
        While FTries > 0 Do
          Try
            If FCTH.DataSize > 0 Then
              While FTries > 0 Do
                Begin
                  FClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
                  If Not FClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty Then
                    Begin
                      FS.Position := 0;
                      FClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, FCTH.DataSize, False);
                      FTries := 0;
                    End
                  Else
                    Begin //no data received within 1 sec
                      Dec(FTries, 1);
                      If FTries = 0 Then
                        Begin //no data received within 5 sec, bad packet
                          FClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                          FCTH.ErrorType := etPacketFailure;
                        End;
                    End;
              End;
            FTries := 0;
          Except
            On E: EIdConnClosedGracefully Do
              Begin //server disconnected
                FTries := 0;
                FClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                FCTH.ErrorType := etServerDropped;
              End;
            On E: EIdReadTimeout Do
              Begin //no data received within 1 sec
                Dec(FTries, 1);
                If FTries = 0 Then
                  Begin //no data received within 5 sec, bad packet
                    FClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                    FCTH.ErrorType := etPacketFailure;
                  End;
              End;
          End;
      Finally
        FreeAndNil(FS);
      End;
      FWaiting := False;
      If Assigned(FOnData) Then
        Synchronize(DataReceived);
    End;
```

I'm trying to validate the stream before trying to retrieve it and just restart the retrieval on read timeout, yet I still run into the intermittent problem where the Reading Thread hangs on trying to read the stream; I'm still able to close the connection and exit the program normally, it just doesn't seem to throw a read exception in some cases.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. That is a lot of code to go through.  StackOverflow is not a debugging service.  What have you done so far to try to troubleshoot the problem yourself?  Your `EIdReadTimeout` handling is worrisome, you are trying to resume reading without knowing where the previous read left off.  That is a good way to corrupt data.  If you get a reading timeout while in the middle of reading something, you should stop what you are doing and start over from the beginning, not try to recover in the middle.

Comment: Sorry about the length, just wanted to make sure you could see both sides with exception handling.  I added the disconnect and read timeouts in the client reading thread and in the Server execute.  Unfortunately I didn't have much to go on for the server side (but there were a few posts that showed using exceptions in the Execute section and the re-Raise them), but I couldn't find anything about exceptions in a reading thread for the client so I made some assumptions.  I wondered if the exception handling is where the issue might be.

Comment: It does appear to be hitting the first read timeout in the stream exceptions.  How would I go about restarting the stream read when it throws the exception?

Comment: Since you don't know the exact byte that timed out, you can't just restart the read. The best way to recover is to simply disconnect the client and make it reconnect, and start the command over from the beginning. Also, by default, Indy uses infinite timeouts, so you must be setting your own timeouts in order to get this error in the first place. So you need to figure out why your timeouts are elapsing. That implies there is an interruption in your communications, either there are network issues, or you are not sending/reading the data correctly to begin with, or the like.

Comment: I'm setting the read timeouts for 1 sec, both sides; and assuming the timeout counters are being reset while actually sending/receiving data, is that correct?

Comment: It is implemented as a per-byte timeout, but 1 sec is way too low.  Typical network lag/latency (especially over mobile) can easily exceed 1 sec.  You really shouldn't be using such low timeouts, especially with TCP and small packets.  10-30 seconds would be more reasonable.  It makes sense to use smaller timeous in between packets while you are waiting for new data to arrive (in case you need to do other other things in the meantime), but use larger timeouts while actually reading the data (in case of slow connections).  But either way, if you do get a timeout, you still need to start over.